# self-written web server cannot be visited by other's computer

Tags: c, sockets, web

I wrote a web server using C language. I can visit the server at `http://myhostname:protnum/index.html`

But when I use my friend's computer to visit the same address, it said cannot visit the web page.

The file is webserv.c, server is launched with ./webserv 12345 (in a terminal)

Why can't my friend computer access the server?
The following is the webserv.c file:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sock, fd;
    FILE *fpin;
    char request[BUFSIZ];

    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: ws portnum\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sock = make_server_socket( atoi(argv[1]) );
    if (sock == -1)
        exit(2);

    /*main loop here*/

    while (1) {
        /*take a call and buffer it*/
        fd = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
        fpin = fdopen(fd, "r");

        /*read request*/
        fgets(request, BUFSIZ, fpin);
        printf("Got a call: request = %s", request);
        read_til_crnl(fpin);

        /*do what client asks*/
        process_rq(request, fd);

        fclose(fpin);
    }

    return 0;
}



int make_server_socket_q(int portnum, int backlog)
 {
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    struct hostent *hp;
    char hostname[HOSTLEN];
    int sock_id;

    sock_id = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock_id == -1)
        return -1;

    /*build address abd bind it to socket*/
    bzero((void *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    gethostname(hostname, HOSTLEN);
    hp = gethostbyname(hostname);

    bcopy((void *)hp->h_addr, (void *)&saddr.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    saddr.sin_port = htons(portnum);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (bind(sock_id, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) != 0)
        return -1;

    if (listen(sock_id, backlog) != 0)
        return -1;

    return sock_id;
 }
void process_rq(char *request, int fd)
{
    char cmd[BUFSIZ], arg[BUFSIZ];

    /*create a new process and return if not the child*/

    if (fork() != 0) 
        return;

    strcpy(arg, "./");
    if (sscanf(request, "%s%s", cmd, arg+2) !=2)
        return;

    if (strcmp(cmd, "GET") != 0)
        cannot_do(fd);
    else if (not_exist(arg))
        do_404(arg, fd);
    else if (isadir(arg))
        do_ls(arg, fd);
    else if (ends_in_cgi(arg))
        do_exec(arg, fd);
    else
        do_cat(arg, fd);
}
```

Comment: Did your program print "Got a call" when your friend attempts connection? Also, some of the functions like `make_server_socket` or `process_rq` are not posted, and probably matter.

Comment: No, my program do not print anything when my friend attempts connection. @Paul

Comment: How is the computer running the server connected to the internet? Is it wireless? Does it connect to a home router box of some kind before connecting to a wired connection?

Comment: I have add the code of the two function.@Paul

Comment: Is your friend your accessing the correct IP address and port ? Can you ping is machine ?

Comment: Did you add exception in Firewall?

Comment: Is there, perhaps a firewall on your machine which may be blocking incoming connections on that port?

Comment: 1. Check on which network your server is listening with "netstat -tan" 2. Make sure your firewall does not block the port (probably 80 TCP)

Comment: You could add fprintf statement to `make_server_socket` to help determine the ip address numbers where it is creating socket.  If these start with 127, 10, or 192, it will only be locally accessible to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common error is to use the wrong address when creating the listening socket. If your listen from `127.0.0.1` only local connections will be accepted. You should listen on `0.0.0.0` to allow connection from any IP address.

To do this in my windows code I've used in the past

```
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = ...;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
```

but seems that `INADDR_ANY` is a better way to say `0`.

Comment: How can I know where I listen? How can I do that?

Comment: @Maybe_hu refer Robert's comment on question for that.

Comment: Yes it does. You can download a stripped down version that starts from your code, adds just the needed headers and removes calls to undefined functions. This code http://raksy.dyndns.org/webserver.c runs fine serving other computers (including my mobile over wifi); you can compile it with `gcc -Wall -O2 -owebserver webserver.c`, there are a couple of warnings because no error checks of any kind are performed. Also remember that if you don't put `SO_REUSEADDR` then you cannot re-run the web server quickly after stopping it.

Comment: It still does not work. What port is your serve using? One explanation is that my computer has a firewall that is blocking connections to the port my server is using. If is that, how can I do? I use the ubuntu 12.04LTS @6502